# What happens in OpenGL if there is a difference between texture channel count and image channel count

Tags: opengl, textures

`glTexImage2D` and `gelTexStorage2D` allows you to set the bit-depth and number of channels to represent the texture pixels by the `internalFormat` parameter. For example GL_R16 would mean mean 16 bit integer values, one channel.

If the source is specified as `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` when a texture is uploaded, I assume that the pixels would be converted to match GL_R16, if that is supported. But what would happen if `format`, which indicates the number of channels in the source data, is more than one. Does it strip the other channels, or would it mix-down to grayscale, or is it an error?

Comment: *"Does it strip the channels"* -Yes it does. If there are to less channels, then the (missing) color channels set 0 and the alpha channels is set 1.